# can't figure out why sound isn't playing with javascript code

Tags: javascript, audio

Thank you to all who have been helping me, but I have one more part I am stuck on.  When the counter in my program reaches the "my_random_number" it should both display a text (which it does) and play a sound.  I am trying to use an IF statement here to make this work.  I have tried many different variations of the code but I can't figure out why it won't play.  It should play a ten-second long tone.  This is where I got the code for the sound --->     `https://jsfiddle.net/njb91z84/113/`

Here is my code....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Javascript CART breakdown calculator</h2>

<button onclick="pause_function()">pause</button>
<button onclick="resume_speed_function()">resume</button>


<label id="seconds">0</label>
<p id="random_number_display"></p>
<p id="breakdown_item"></p>


<script>

var my_random_number, low, high;
low = 1;
high = 5;
my_random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * high) + low;
document.getElementById("random_number_display").innerHTML = my_random_number;

var random_breakdown_event, low_event, high_event;
low_event = 1
high_event = 9
random_breakdown_event = Math.floor(Math.random() * high_event) + low_event;
var text

if (random_breakdown_event == 1) text = "blown engine";
if (random_breakdown_event == 2) text = "broken transmission";
if (random_breakdown_event == 3) text = "broken suspension";
if (random_breakdown_event == 4) text = "broken halfshaft";
if (random_breakdown_event == 5) text = "broken cv joint";
if (random_breakdown_event == 6) text = "broken wings";
if (random_breakdown_event == 7) text = "electrical misfire";
if (random_breakdown_event == 8) text = "broken fuel pump";
if (random_breakdown_event == 9) text = "change battery";

var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
var interval_between_ticks = 1000;
//Assign the interval to a variable to keep track of it
var interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);

function setTime() {
++totalSeconds;
secondsLabel.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
if(my_random_number === totalSeconds){
document.getElementById("breakdown_item").innerHTML = text}

if(my_random_number === totalSeconds){
function myFunction(frequency, duration, callback) {

var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
duration = 10000 / 1000;     // the 10000 used to be 'duration' 
oscillator.type = 'square';
oscillator.frequency.value = 500; // value in hertz
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
oscillator.onended = callback;
oscillator.start(0);
oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + duration);
}
}
}

function  pause_function() {
interval_between_ticks = 999999999;
//Clear the old interval so we don't have memory leaks
clearInterval(interval);
//Set the interval with the new time between clicks
interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);
}

function  resume_speed_function() {
interval_between_ticks = 1000;
//Clear the old interval so we don't have memory leaks
clearInterval(interval);
//Set the interval with the new time between clicks
interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo: you are not calling the function `myFunction` in this if block, you are only declaring it. Move this declaration somewhere else for readiblity and only call it in this if block: https://jsfiddle.net/haw6jqrm/

Comment: it's the little stuff that's been tripping me up like this thanks!

Comment: Since this question is very unlikely to be found by anyone facing the same issue (even if there will be), it is probably better for you to delete it. I already cast a Vote To Close to this effect, but this requires the work of 4 more reviewers to attain the same result.